# iPhone - UITableView left and right justification

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am putting in a uitableview and I'd like to have each row divided into left and right. Sort of like this: http://blog.danilocampos.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/photo.jpg

Can someone explain how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want a cell built with the `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` style.

You can create that kind of cell this way:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyle1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdenfitierString];
```

From there you can get the cell's `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` properties and adjust font sizes, etc. as necessary.